# Can't get $_post value from controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery

I collect a code for country and state, where I select one of country name from select tag and under the country all the state show in next select box. All the data come from MySQL and is processed by jQuery, ajax.

I can not get value from controller. Why?

```
$data=$this->input->post('state',true)
```

My code is below: CI in model

```
<?php
/* File : ajax.php
 * Author : Manish Kumar Jangir
*/
class AJAX {

    private $database = NULL;
    private $_query = NULL;
    private $_fields = array();
    public  $_index = NULL;
    const DB_HOST = "localhost";
    const DB_USER = "root";
    const DB_PASSWORD = "";
    const DB_NAME = "csc";


    public function __construct(){
        $this->db_connect();                    // Initiate Database connection
        $this->process_data();
    }

    /*
     *  Connect to database
    */
    private function db_connect(){
        $this->database = mysql_connect(self::DB_HOST,self::DB_USER,self::DB_PASSWORD);
        if($this->database){
            $db =  mysql_select_db(self::DB_NAME,$this->database);
        } else {
            echo mysql_error();die;
        }
    }

    private function process_data(){
        $this->_index = ($_REQUEST['index'])?$_REQUEST['index']:NULL;
        $id = ($_REQUEST['id'])?$_REQUEST['id']:NULL;
        switch($this->_index){
            case 'country':
                $this->_query = "SELECT * FROM countries";
                $this->_fields = array('id','country_name');
                break;
            case 'state':
                $this->_query = "SELECT * FROM states WHERE country_id=$id";
                $this->_fields = array('id','state_name');
                break;
            case 'city':
                $this->_query = "SELECT * FROM cities WHERE state_id=$id";
                $this->_fields = array('id','city_name');
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        $this->show_result();
    }

    public function show_result(){
        echo '<option value="">Select '.$this->_index.'</option>';
        $query = mysql_query($this->_query);
        while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $entity_id = $result[$this->_fields[0]];
            $enity_name = $result[$this->_fields[1]];
            echo "<option value='$entity_id'>$enity_name</option>";
        }
    }
}

$obj = new AJAX;

?>
```

This is my view:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Country State City Dependent Dropdown using Ajax</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
body{
    font-family:arial;
    color:#666;
}
form select{
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius:4px;
    width:120px;
}

form label{
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    load_options('','country');
});

function load_options(id,index){
    $("#loading").show();
    if(index=="state"){
        $("#city").html('<option value="">Select city</option>');
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/welcome/includ.html?index="+index+"&id="+id,
        complete: function(){$("#loading").hide();},
        success: function(data) {
            $("#"+index).html(data);
        }
    })
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:800px; margin:auto;padding-top:100px;">
<h1>Country,State,City dynamic dependent dropdown using Ajax and Jquery</h1>
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/city_ajax/show_result" method="post">
        <label>Select Country</label>
        <select id="country" onchange="load_options(this.value,'state');">
            <option value="">Select country</option>
        </select>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <label>Select State</label>
        <select id="state" onchange="load_options(this.value,'city');">
            <option value="">Select state</option>
        </select>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <label>Select city</label>
        <select id="city">
            <option value="">Select City</option>
        </select>
        <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>loader.gif" id="loading" align="absmiddle" style="display:none;"/>
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT statements:

`country_id=$id` should be  `country_id='" . $id . "'`

`state_id=$id` should be  `state_id='" . $id . "'`

Comment: They're are in double quotes, so variable were parsed nonetheless. Also, it would be a good thing to sanitize the ID casting it to an integer

Comment: yes the ajax.php is a .php file. are you help me to convert as codeigniter model and controller file. and i am edit the type:"post", but i can not get yet the value in controller of $data=$this->input->post('country',true);    $data=$this->input->post('state',true); and  I do not understand where I will change country_id='" . $id . "' and state_id='" . $id . "' please help me(I am new at program world)

Answer (score 0):

As you said CI model :

in CodeIgniter you have to extend CI_Model as :

```
  class Exam_model extends CI_Model {}
```

in order to make it CI model other wise it is just a .php file

And

about this

```
    $data=$this->input->post('state',true);
```

you are trying to assess a **post** parameter which needs to a **type in ajax** as POST

```
     url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/welcome/includ.html?index="+index+"&id="+id,
    complete: function(){$("#loading").hide();},
    type:"POST", // you have to mention post type here
    success: function(data) {
        $("#"+index).html(data);
    }
```

Hope it will help!

Comment: yes the ajax.php is a .php file. are you help me to convert as codeigniter model and controller file. and i am edit the type:"post", but i can not get yet the value in controller of $data=$this->input->post('country',true); $data=$this->input->post('state',true); please help me